# Is Obi-Wan Kenobi particularly gifted at Jedi mind tricks?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

If we take a look and compare each Jedi (or Force user) and their track record when it comes to using the iconic [Jedi mind trick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_trick) (not so "Jedi", it seems), a Force ability used to influence the thoughts of others, Obi-Wan stands out:

[image]

Obi-Wan stands out even more when we take into account failed attempts at using mind tricks:

[image]

### **Question:** is Obi-Wan's pattern of frequent and highly successful mind trick use a coincidence or is it attributable to something else (like natural talent or skill)?

Essentially I'm looking for a reference, if it exists, from Star Wars canon, which could support either possibility, or a definitive "No, there is no such reference" answer (which would support and suggest "Coincidence"). *Legends* won't be accepted as a valid source, but will be regarded as interesting trivia if a canonical reference is absent.

---

Note: the numbers in the graphs were mined from the [*History* section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_trick#History) of the *Mind trick* article on Wookieepedia, which contains cited claims with valid sources, all of which are also part of the new *Star Wars* canon.

Comment: Mind tricks don't work on Stack Exchange, only money!

Comment: OMG, Force abilities mapped out on a **graph**??? My day is complete.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Glad to read someone else out there shares my enthusiasm for this.

Comment: Some of the failed attempts were due to the fact that the recipient was immune, so I don't know if it should count in the first place...

Comment: Maybe it's just the former scientist in me, but I don't see a statistical significance or aberration in the data.

Comment: @KyleKanos 400% increase in any statistic is significant. When every other Force user in the galaxy has been portrayed to only mind trick **once** successfully (or even zero times), and Kenobi does so 5 times, it stands out.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I think your count $N$ is what's the issue, it's too small to make any inferences from.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm not making **any** inferences, I'm saying "Look, this stands out to me - is it just a coincidence or does his character happen to be good at this?"

Comment: @GhotiandChips you're asking others to make inferences from the data...swap 'mind tricks' with 'coin flips landing heads' can you make any statements about the successes in that case?

Comment: @KyleKanos "you're asking others to make inferences from the data" Nonsense, I didn't ask such a thing. I used and presented the data to justify my question, and then my question is after an actual reference from the canon in which Obi-Wan's talent/ability is shown to be significant (as an invented example, a conversation where this phenomenon is brought up and someone replies, "That's why Obi-Wan is so effective in his ability to compel others" etc.), so I flatly reject your claim that I'm asking people to make inferences based on the data I present.

Comment: Maybe Obi-Wan is just really good at reading people to predict who's "weak-minded" enough for it to work.  By comparison, other Jedi appear to rely on the law of averages.

Comment: @GhotiandChips okay, I can see your point there, you're not asking for inferences. But I reject the notion that anything stands out because there is not enough instances to have a meaningful measure.

Comment: So are your charts wrong then? Because it looks like 4 on both to me. You're also biasing towards a main character who appears in 4 films vs side characters and a highly untrained main character.

Comment: @KyleKanos No, it's 4 (I deleted my comment since I can't edit), I thought 5 because of a conversation with someone where they claimed that Ben causing a sound to sneak past two stormtroopers in Episode IV was a mind trick. I corrected them saying he used telekinetic, not telepathic, abilities to physically cause a sound, since we, the audience can hear it. **Yes** It *is* biased, exactly, we get most of our mind trick screentime with Obi-Wan, so here I am wondering if someone who has seen and read everything Star Wars knows whether they address this or not.

Comment: It's true that we have a "on screen time" bias here.

Comment: @Edelk Going with canonical bias, actually.

Comment: By "Jedi Mind Tricks", are you only referring to when a person uses the Force to change somebody's decision? What about when somebody uses the Force to read somebody's secret thoughts. Vader and Palpatine did that a few times in novelizations of the movies and in canon novels.

Comment: Shouldn't Rey have two attempts, with one failed? She tried to persuade the guard to release her and he refused, then she tried again and it worked.

Comment: @KSmarts Nah - she merely repeated her instructions immediately afterwards in the same scene and succeeded. By the logic you present, we should also tally all the times people like Qui-Gonn tried, failed, tried again and failed again as additional attempts/fails. That's rather silly.

Comment: @RichS What I'm referring to is hyperlinked in the question for those who don't know what a Jedi mind trick is.

Comment: I'm with KSmarts on this one, Rey should have a fail mark too. If you pull the trigger on a gun and nothing happens, its a misfire, even if it works the second time. I don't know about marking each of Qui-Gon's fails because the being he was attempting them on is immune, so it was less an issue of Qui-Gon being unsuccessful in his attempt than of him just choosing the wrong subject. If your playing an RPG and get a good hit with a fireball, but the enemy turns out to be immune to fire, you still got a good roll.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently each jedi has a specific talent in force related skills. If you read the any of the Knights of the Old Republic comics/books as well as the X Wing series by Michael Stackpole, it explains that some jedi have an affinity for certain skills, for instance Corran Horn had a talent for illusion/persuasion based abilities but couldnt perform basic telekinesis unless under extreme pressure.

Comment: Although this is kinda interesting, does it refer to Kenobi?

Comment: not directly but the idea that each jedi has a talent could be why Kenobi's mind tricks are successful, he is called the "negotiator" for a reason.

Comment: Are those comics/books still canon? If so, perhaps you can expand you answer.

Comment: this is half of the problem with answering this one, the x-wing books arent canon anymore but the knights of the old republic books are in this kind of middle ground where disney say that anything after the films isnt canon but constantly borrows elements from it. As far as KOTOR being canon, KOTOR, the mandalorian wars, thrawn etc are mentioned in Rebels making them canon, until disney say otherwise.

Comment: Who is he called "The Negotiator" by?

Comment: General Grevious in episode III. It was also referenced as Kenobis nickname in the book "ultimate starwars" which was an official guide made for fans of the movies.